# ajax call to a file goes through the first time, gets a 404 error the second time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having some trouble with a function using jQuery post. The function is supposed to run itself several times and then stop, which it has done successfully in the past. What is happening now is that the first time it runs the function, the php script executes fine. When it tries to run itself again, I get a 404 error. 
Here's the javascript function:

```
function ajax_call(senddata){
    $.post("/script.php", senddata,
        function(data) {
            if(data.pointer != "done"){
                setTimeout(ajax_call(data), 100);
            }
        }, "json");
}
```

The output of the php file is:

```
{"pointer": "1234"}
```

The error is occuring in a wordpress plugin I'm writing and displays as:
POST http://xxxxx.local/script.php 404 (Not Found)  - load-scripts.php

As I said, the first time it works. The php file runs with no errors, so the file exists, and I'm calling it correctly in the function. It has worked in the past and I've reverted both scripts to a point in which I know it worked. If anyone has any ideas as to what would be causing this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It can not be a server side issue unless the php script is using cookies and counting requests made by specific ips/websites and blocking them only after the first request. Unless that's the case, you need to go through your client side coding. And please post a link of the concerned website.

Comment: Is there any other server side problem that could be causing this? I've uploaded the files to a live site and everything works fine there. I would post a link but it's all in the back end of a wordpress site.

Comment: More possibilities are there, but they can be ignored. Such as, the server blacklists you after the very first request. But then, why would it reply with a 404 error, when first request was a success? The first requests highlights you in the server's algorithm as a bot or a site crawler. And some others, but the thing that makes them senseless is, you are being allowed to make the first request. Is the ip being changed between requests? If not, then the fault is at the client side scripting.

Comment: If you could link the site in question, I would send some fake post requests and will check if I'm being treated the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your JS.  What I would do is use firebug or F12 in IE to see what's going on over the network (network tab).  Check the request and response detail and make sure everything makes sense.

After that I'd check the server logs to see if you can see anything about that 404'ing request.